# Is it possible to get an HTML representation (serialization) of a form including user's input modifications?

Tags: xml, forms, dom, serialization, user-input

Type in something in a input[type=text]. form.innerHTML will not return what was typed in (it does make sense to me).
Check in a checkbox. form.innerHTML will not return the checkbox with a checked attribute.
The same happens for radio buttons and so on for every kind of input ...

I don't want to use input events (like blur, focus, etc). I do want to know if there are some standard native API.

I've tried also XMLSerializer and I hadn't success.

UPDATE:
I want to use plain JavaScript. No jQuery or any other library/framework.

jQuery's serialize does get the user input and it's great! The problem is, if the element doesn't have a name, it's not included and I do need it!

UPDATE 2:

element.value returns what was typed in a input[type=text], element.getAttribute('value') returns what is in HTML value attribute (input value="some-value") ! O.O

Is this behavior documented anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use jQuery, there is a helpful function called serialize.

```
 $("#yourForm").serialize();
```

Comment: Put a name attribute on the element and serialize will return it:
http://jsfiddle.net/55xnJ/44/